# Find value in json tree and return the path

Tags: javascript

I have data with children, i have to find element by name and print the path to element. I wrote search fucntion that finds the element, but can't handle with PATH. Where i should handle it? How to add or remove path while searching?

```
 let data = {
type: "folder",
name: "animals",
children: [
    {
        type: "folder",
        name: "cat",
        children: [
            {
                type: "folder",
                name: "images",
                children: [
                    {
                        type: "file",
                        name: "cat001.jpg"
                    }, {
                        type: "file",
                        name: "cat002.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                type: "folder",
                name: "images",
                children: [
                    {
                        type: "file",
                        name: "cat001.jpg"
                    }, {
                        type: "file",
                        name: "cat002.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "folder",
        name: "dog",
        children: [
            {
                type: "folder",
                name: "images",
                children: [
                    {
                        type: "file",
                        name: "dog001.jpg"
                    }, {
                        type: "file",
                        name: "dog002.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "file",
        name: "horse.png"
    },
    {
        type: "file",
        name: "bear.png"
    },
    {
        type: "file",
        name: "horse.png"
    }
]
```

};

```
search(data, name, path = "") {
    if (data.name == name) {
        let path = [data.name];
        return path;
    } else if (data.children != null) {
        let result = null;
        for (let i = 0; result == null && i < data.children.length; i++) {
            result = this.search(data.children[i], name);
        }
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to the path once you've found something:

```
… if (data.children != null) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++) {
        let result = this.search(data.children[i], name);
        if (result) {
            result.unshift("children", i); // or whatever you want in your path
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```